# Getting values from a multi column listbox VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, listbox, multiple-columns

I am in need of help, I am trying to get all three columns of my multi column list box in a for loop, it should be pretty simple but I cannot figure it out,

I have googled for hours and to be honest haven't gotten anywhere as everyone wants it to be able to select and then loop through where as i just want to loop through all of them and take them to separate strings,

Hope this makes sense,

Thank you,

Comment: What did you try?  did the `.list` property not show itself?

Comment: Hello, I have tried .List and .Listindex but i cannot work it out, I am working hard now to try and do it, ill have a further look into .list

Comment: Thank you @Nathan_Sav this has helped a lot :) All done

Comment: remember, `Me.listbox1.list()` is , in tour case a 2D array, and 0 based. (starts at 0, stops at `.listcount-1` ).

Comment: For further reference, here is an example of the first colum from the selected item in listbox1: `str = listbox1.list ( listbox1.listindex,0)  ` .

Answer (score 1):

You can cycle through entries in the list by using the script below and fill a new array which can be pasted to an assigned range on the sheet of the same size as the array

```
dim arrayctr as integer, i as integer, myarray() as variant
   
With mylistbox

    'below sizes array to size of list in listbox.
    'use arrctr to populate selected items to array without blank entries in between.
    redim myarray(1 to .listcount, 1 to 1) as variant

   '.listcount gives total entries, but list starts from 0 so use i-1 to get values

    For i = 1 to .listcount 
      if .selected(i-1) = true then myarray(arrayctr) = .list(i-1): _
      arrctr = arrctr + 1
    Next i

End with
```

you can use For next loop through entries and use `Exit For` when the value of the array = `""` so it handles only entries with data in and avoids pointless calculations.

I have had similar troubles with finding online answers to some questions such as this, I hope it helps!